# How to use TCPROS for multi-robot communication

Tags: ros, tcpros, multimaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Community,
I was wondering if it is possible to use TCPROS to send directed messages to another robot. You could assume that both robots are configurable however desired and are have separate ROS masters. Could someone please tell me how this could be done?
Thanks
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44064/how-to-use-tcpros-for-multi-robot-communication/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are currently three tools - foreign relay, master_sync and fkie. Some of us on the multimaster sig are working on putting together a new gateway model (about 40% complete).

Best advice is to check the [multimaster sig](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sig/Multimaster) for more information and to track development.

[master_sync](http://ros.org/wiki/multimaster) does directed flipping. It can flip specific local topics/services to a remote master and is configurable from yaml or from code. It doesn't work on fuerte though. [rocon_master_sync](https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_orchestration/tree/master/rocon_master_sync) is a patched version of master_sync for fuerte. [rocon_linux_app_platform](https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_linux_app_platform) makes use of it and [turtle concert](http://redmine.robotconcert.org/projects/concert_framework/wiki/Turtle_Concert_Demo) is a working demo.

Master sync though is only two-master. To scale up, we're in the middle of creating a [gateway model](http://redmine.robotconcert.org/projects/multimaster/wiki/Gateway%20Model) for flipping/requesting topics between peers in a multimaster environment. It's very crudely flipping publishers and services right now and we're targetting for it to be reasonably polished within a month.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on 2012-09-19**:
I looked into all the three techniques. Foreign relay is command line only so cannot be called through a node. multimaster_fkie exposes the entire master to other. We will have multiple different masters on the network so it will result in enormous data transfer. We're looking for directed msgs..

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-09-19**:
Added comments in an edit above (too long for these boxes).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may be interested in [foreign_relay](http://ros.org/wiki/foreign_relay)

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on 2012-09-19**:
I checked out foreign_relay previously. However it does not host a service that I could call to send directed messages to a foreign master. The only applications I saw with foreign_relay were using the terminal. Do you know how to send messages through a running node?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-09-19**:
So are you looking for something closer to being able to call a service another robot with a remote rosmaster?

**Comment by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on 2012-09-19**:
Yes essentially be able to send a msg on another robot's topic through a running node. So be able to publish externally..

**Comment by [hiccup](https://answers.ros.org/users/4760/hiccup/) on 2013-04-25**:
Can the master_sync (multi master package) be used for a robot master in groovy as well?